# SPFx how to set a people field in a list, e.g. “convert” AccountName to Lookup ID?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, user-accounts, person, clientpeoplepicker

I am trying to build an SPFx WebPart with React Office UI Fabric. I have a SharePoint list with a People field called `AssignedTo`. The `lookup ID` values are like `12`, `20`, and so on. When I select a person with the `PeoplePicker`, I get `AccountName` like `i:0#.f|membership|bob@somewhere.org.nz` and a `GUID` like `ff53b41e-d11a-435c-9cd1-d708e71ee7c7`.

I think the `lookup IDs` like `12` refer to the `UserInfo` list. I have seen calls to `web.EnsureUser`, in other SharePoint projects, but the Web object (`this.context.pageContext.web`) in SPFx doesn't seem to have those methods.

All the People we try to use are Office 365 users. How do I "convert" the information from the `PeoplePicker` to the `lookup IDs`, the `People column` in the list is using?

Any help is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to api/web/ensureuser using the SPHttpClient is needed. It ensures the requested user is loaded into the SharePoint site userinfo. Using the given AccountName like i:0#.f|membership|bob@somewhere.org.nz from the search as parameter. The returned SPUser contains the Id field for the Lookup column. I implemented the following method:

```
public EnsureUser(userName: string): Promise<ISPUser> {
  console.log("SharePointDataProvider.EnsureUser( \"" + userName + "\" )");
  var data = {logonName: userName};

  return this._webPartContext.spHttpClient.post(
    this._ensureUserUrl, 
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    { body: JSON.stringify(data) } ).then(
      (value: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        console.log("SharePointDataProvider.EnsureUser FullFill: statusText:\"" + value.statusText + "\"" );
        return value.json();
      },
      (error: any) => console.log("SharePointDataProvider.EnsureUser Rejected: " + error )
    ).then((json: ISPUser) => {
        console.log("SharePointDataProvider.EnsureUser FullFill: Id:" + json.Id +" LoginName:\"" + json.LoginName + "\"" );
      return json;
  });
}
```

My mini ISPUser interface:

```
interface ISPUser
{
    Email: string;
    Id: number;
    LoginName: string;
    Title: string;
}
```